# sqlite3 symbol not found when I run "rails server"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

I'm not longer able to start my server. Have no idea what happened, but I'm getting this error when I run "rails s":

```
Core:pocketbook lee$ rails s
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _sqlite3_initialize
  Referenced from: /Users/lee/Dropbox/Apps/pocketbook/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.3.1/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _sqlite3_initialize
  Referenced from: /Users/lee/Dropbox/Apps/pocketbook/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.3.1/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

It's weird though because I'm using ruby 1.9.2 with rvm. When I run "which ruby", it retruns ".rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin/ruby"

Not sure what I could have done to cause this problem.

Comment: I got rid of RVM using "RVM implode" and then reinstalled it. That seemed to fix some issues, but at some point I must have deleted a lib directory because when I attempted to install rails I got "File not found: lib"

Comment: Also, when I run "bundle install" it appears to work correctly, but when I then try to start my server with "rails server" I get a bunch of sqlite related errors. To test this, I tried to install sqlite3-ruby on my machine outside of bundler and I get these errors: ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3-ruby:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
...
checking for sqlite3_libversion_number() in -lsqlite3... yes
checking for rb_proc_arity()... yes
checking for sqlite3_initialize()... no
sqlite3-ruby only supports sqlite3 versions 3.6.16+, please upgrade!
*** extconf.rb failed ***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this problem come up a few times one of the reason it could be cause this to happen is dew to the version of sqlite3 being the wrong version. Some times you can have the sqlite3-ruby gem installed but not be compatible with the sqlite version your running.

Make sure your sqlite3 version is higher then 3.6.16

To check just run sqlite3 -version and you will know. Simple solution is just to update the sqlite.

I had this error happen when I decided to remove any trace of mac ports and switch over to [brew](https://brew.sh/)

Answer (score 3):

Ok,  it appears that the latest version of sqlite3 doesn't work well with OS X Leopard. So, I had to specify the version of sqlite3 to use in my gemfile. I added this line:

`gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.2.5', :require => 'sqlite3'`

FYI to anyone else having these problems.

Answer (score 0):

you might also check your location `pwd`, check if you are at the right level (path)...sounds stupid but i just spen one hour trying to solve this and the only thing that changed was a path (palmface) everything was just fine